# Using 4G mobile router to create my home network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking

I am getting into web development for the first time and my purpose now is to test my website from external devices.

I have a mobile router. What I would like to do is to create a home network in such a way that all the devices connected to the router (wirelessly) would be part of the same network, to (e.g.) be able to see the prototype of the website I am building on my laptop through my smartphone. Is this possible?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, and I personally don't have great experience with networking stuff, so I hope my question is clear.

**EDIT 1**

Just to clarify a bit what I would like to do... I am following [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/python-web-server-with-flask/worksheet/) on setting up a webserver using Raspberry and Flask. In step 7 ("Browsing on other devices"), it reads *Since we used host='0.0.0.0', on the app.run line, the web server is accessible to any device on the same network, including other computers, tablets, and smartphones.*(...) *Open up a web browser on the other device and enter the Raspberry Pi's IP address into the address bar with :5000 on the end e.g. http://192.168.1.3:5000/*.

Of course, I use the laptop IP instead of the Raspberry one. However, the content of the page is not showed from my smartphone.

The router is a Vodafone R216-Z 4G WiFi (I found some specs at [this page](http://www.4gltemall.com/vodafone-r216-z-4g-mobile-wifi-hotspot.html)).

Comment: I am not exactly sure what is the actual problem? As I understand you have a router that connects internet using 4G network and it has WiFi enabled and this is your WLAN. Is it correct? So are all mobile devices you want to use to test connecting to this WiFi Network? If so then these devices are actually inside your home network (WLAN). What you need to do now is to connect your laptop to the same WiFi network (the same WLAN), start web server on this laptop and connect to this web server from mobile devices using local ip address of your laptop.

Comment: You understood my situation. When I connect my laptop and my smartphone to the 4g router (i.e. connecting  to the same SSID), I launched the webserver from the laptop and I can test it is working from it using 'localhost' (to see my webpage). Unfortunately, I cannot see the same page from the smartphone addressing the laptop's IP. The webserver is set so that it should be visible to the others devices connected to the same network.

Comment: @umbe1987: Routers normally have a setting called *Client Isolation* or similar which prevents devices on the network from seeing each other. However, some 4G routers may not allow you to control this since they are typically used as access points only. You should go in to the router's configuration page to look for this setting.

Comment: What page do you see through your smartphone when attempting to connect to the website? Are you using a CSM such as WordPress? If you've installed WordPress and configured it to use "localhost" in the "Wordpress address" and "site address" then you will only see the text served by the website - the CSS and possibly other resources may not show - which is because you need to change the addresses to the IP of your laptop. This is exactly why web developers have their own hosting or VPS/dedicated server because you have a domain name that everything connects to rather than IPs and "localhost"

Comment: +1 for James's comment regarding "Client Isolation"

Comment: @JamesP Thanks. Unfortunately, in the router's configuration page, I couldn't find anything related to 'client isolation'. Just something about DMZ and MAC configuration (which appears to be kind of useful, but I am not that sure about it). Anyway, would this lack be negligible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Big Chris It's just the typical "Cannot visualize the page". I am not using Wordpress, just HTML, CSS, and Flask. Thanks.

Comment: Can you ping your laptop from another device? If you can't then, as James says, it may have Client Isolation may be configured and (from what I've just looked up on the Vodafone manual) you can't configure anything on that device form the normal interface. You'd be looking at a whole new network setup unfortunately... OR, buy some cheap hosting where you can configure your own domain and point your devices to this (how the majority of "production" websites are done).

Comment: @JamesP Well, there's actually one unflagged button saying "Allow guest users to access the mobile broad band network settings". Would this be related to 'client isolation'?

Comment: Probably not as it states to access the network settings so doesn't sound remotely related to allowing the network to talk to each other...

Comment: I tried to ping my laptop from my phone and it times out. Anyway, to find the IP I ran 'ifconfig' from the terminal, and took the 'inet' address from 'wlp4s0' row as my IP. is this correct? I'd prefer not buying anything but the essential, as what I'm doing is just for fun (for now). I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @umbe1987: It could be worth trying with `debug=False` instead to see if it makes any difference

Comment: @James P Thanks. Unfortunately I had no luck with that neither, nor using a WndowsPhone nor an Android Phone. I guess it has to be with the 'client isolation' stuff, and apparently there's no way from the router's settings to disable it. Any suggestion to do that, or another approach I should consider in order to have my laptop and my mobile phones talking to each others?

Comment: @umbe1987: Please also try to disable firewall on your laptop. If you have firewall enabled it may block incomming connection to your laptop on non-default 5000 port.

Comment: @running.t Great! that worked perfectly! I have to admit that since I didn't have the knowledge to think about the firewall blocking the port, I would have never got it working... I ran from the terminal 'sudo ufw allow 5000' (ufw is UncomplicatedFirewall) and magically the site appeared in my Windows Phone! Thank you so much, I would be happy to accept your answer if you turn your comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussion in comments it looks like the problem is firewall running on your laptop, which does not allow incoming connections on non-standard ports e.g. 5000 port. Please try disabling your laptop firewall or adding appropriate firewall rule to accept incoming connections on 5000 port.